# Why is my output not getting assigned a value?

Tags: verilog

I'm working on a decoder for part of a larger project. I have two counters that act as input to this module. One of them counts 0 - 15, and another one increments once when the first counter reaches 15. Depending on the value of the counters, the decoder outputs a different value. Usually it's either 0, 1, or -1, but occasionally it has to be 0.707 or -0.707 and we are using fixed point numbers temporarily to deal with that.

The issue I'm having is that with my test code, I can't get my output to be assigned as soon as the counters start running. I have reduced my simulation code to a very simple test where I trigger the reset on and off really quick, then assign the first counter to be 1, then the second counter to be 1, which should make the decoder assign 1 to the output. It's stuck outputting 'XXXXXX'.

Prior to this, I had a long list of 'else if' statements performing the assignments, and I had the same error.

I'm positive the error is really simple, but I just haven't been able to see it.

Verilog Code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module Decoder_W
(
    input clk,
    input rst,
    input [31:0] counter,
    input [31:0] stage_counter,
    output reg [31:0] out_W
);

always @ (posedge(clk)) 
begin

if (rst == 1)
    out_W <= 0;

else if (stage_counter == 32'd1)
    begin 
        case (counter)
            32'd0: out_W <= 1;
            32'd1: out_W <= -1;
            32'd2: out_W <= 1;
            32'd3: out_W <= -1;
            32'd4: out_W <= 1;
            32'd5: out_W <= -1;
            32'd6: out_W <= 1;
            32'd7: out_W <= -1;
            32'd8: out_W <= 0;
            32'd9: out_W <= 0;
            32'd10: out_W <= 0;
            32'd11: out_W <= 0;
            32'd12: out_W <= 0;
            32'd13: out_W <= 0;
            32'd14: out_W <= 0;
            32'd15: out_W <= 0; 
            default out_W <= 0;
        endcase
     end

else if (stage_counter == 32'd2)
    begin
        case (counter)
            32'd0: out_W <= 1;
            32'd1: out_W <= 0;
            32'd2: out_W <= -1;
            32'd3: out_W <= 0;
            32'd4: out_W <= 1;
            32'd5: out_W <= 0;
            32'd6: out_W <= -1;
            32'd7: out_W <= 0;
            32'd8: out_W <= 0;
            32'd9: out_W <= -1;
            32'd10: out_W <= 0;
            32'd11: out_W <= 1;
            32'd12: out_W <= 0;
            32'd13: out_W <= -1;
            32'd14: out_W <= 0;
            32'd15: out_W <= 1;
            default out_W <= 0;       
         endcase
     end

else if (stage_counter == 32'd3)
    begin
        case (counter)
            32'd0: out_W <= 1;
            32'd1: out_W <= 0;
            32'd2: out_W <= 0;
            32'd3: out_W <= 32'b11111111111111111110100101100000;
            32'd4: out_W <= -1;
            32'd5: out_W <= 32'b11111111111111111110100101100000;
            32'd6: out_W <= 0;
            32'd7: out_W <= 32'b00000000000000000001011010100000;
            32'd8: out_W <= 0;
            32'd9: out_W <= 32'b11111111111111111110100101100000;
            32'd10: out_W <= -1;
            32'd11: out_W <= 32'b11111111111111111110100101100000;
            32'd12: out_W <= 0;
            32'd13: out_W <= 32'b00000000000000000001011010100000;
            32'd14: out_W <= 1;
            32'd15: out_W <= 32'b00000000000000000001011010100000;
            default out_W <= 0;       
         endcase
     end

else
    out_W <= 0;

end
endmodule
```

Testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module testbench;

reg clk = 0;
reg rst = 0;
reg [31:0] counter = 0;
reg [31:0] stage_counter = 0;
wire [31:0] out_W = 0;

Decoder_W test
(
    .clk(clk),
    .rst(rst),
    .counter(counter),
    .stage_counter(stage_counter),
    .out_W(out_W)
);

integer i = 0;

always #5 clk = ~clk;
initial 
begin
#10 rst = 0;
#10 rst = 1;
#10 rst = 0;
#10 stage_counter = 1;
#10 counter = 0;
#10 counter = 1;
#30

$finish;
end
endmodule
```

Simulation Output:
[image: Link to Verilog Simulation Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get X on your output because of contention.  `out_W` in the testbench has 2 drivers: the `wire`, which is continually driving 0, and the `Decoder_W` module, which drives 1 then 'hffff_ffff.

To fix it, don't assign a value to the `wire`.  Change:

```
wire [31:0] out_W = 0;
```

to:

```
wire [31:0] out_W;
```

Answer (score -1):

out_W is an output wire hence you are not supposed to init it. Try the below code.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

 module testbench;

  reg clk;
  reg rst;
  reg [31:0] counter;
  reg [31:0] stage_counter;
  wire [31:0] out_W;

  Decoder_W test
  (
    .clk(clk),
    .rst(rst),
    .counter(counter),
    .stage_counter(stage_counter),
    .out_W(out_W)
   );

   integer i = 0;

   always #5 clk = ~clk;
   initial 
   begin
         clk = 0;
         rst = 0;
         counter = 0;
         stage_counter = 0;
     #10 rst = 1;
     #10 rst = 0;
     #10 stage_counter = 1;
     #10 counter = 0;
     #10 counter = 1;
     #30
    $finish;
  end
 endmodule
```